# React how to recognize users without registration?

Tags: reactjs

I'm creating an app for users to create movie reviews but I would like to avoid registration. User comes in writes review and is done. User comes back checks all his reviews and is done. I would like to do something like this android app called [Whisper](http://whisper.sh/) but I'm not sure if they identify users using MAC Address or something like that.

Reviews will be stored in database assigned to an unique id. What's left is how can I persist the user without having him create an account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `localStorage` for example, store a user ID there that's generated on the first visit. However, this will fail once the user clears their browser data (or, obviously, changes their device), so it's certainly nothing more than a 'toy' solution. `localStorage` data is flushed commonly alongside history wipes.

Another simple solution would be the above, but with introducing a way to let the user provide their unique passphrase and store it in `localStorage`, so until they switch devices or flush their browser data, they do not have to provide the passphrase on subsequent visits.

Other than that, there's no way to achieve so. This is basically what browser fingerprinting wants to get done (identify users across visits and websites), but it's quite fallible, far too fallible to rely on for purposes of persisting any important data. Fingerprints change more or less depending on the agent, but pretty much always they do change given enough time.

The Android app is using some, well, Android things. If you're making just a webapp, you're out of luck.